# Is there a way to Reload the Primary GEPlugin Database?

Tags: javascript, html, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

So what I want to do is to replace the main database loaded into a Google Earth GEPlugin instance in a web browser. If I go to the Code Playground: [Here http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#mars/alternate_server_connectivity](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#mars/alternate_server_connectivity)

Then I get an example of loading a new database. However, if I try to make the CreateInstance calls multiple times, I keep getting the same database (I am guessing this is due to the GEPlugin.exe running in the background still using the first database. If I remove that instance by killing the geplugin.exe process then the load works)

On that code page for an example edit the HTML and I used the following html/script combo

```
    <!--
You are free to copy and use this sample in accordance with the terms of the
Apache license (http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html)
-->
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Google Earth API Sample</title>
    <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=ABQIAAAAuPsJpk3MBtDpJ4G8cqBnjRRaGTYH6UMl8mADNa0YKuWNNa8VNxQCzVBXTx2DYyXGsTOxpWhvIG7Djw" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var ge;

    google.load("earth", "1");

    function init() {
      google.earth.createInstance('map3d', initCallback, failureCallback,
        { database: 'http://khmdb.google.com/?db=mars' });

    }

    function initCallback(instance) {
      ge = instance;
      ge.getWindow().setVisibility(true);

      // add a navigation control
      ge.getNavigationControl().setVisibility(ge.VISIBILITY_AUTO);

      document.getElementById('installed-plugin-version').innerHTML =
        ge.getPluginVersion().toString();
    }

    function failureCallback(errorCode) {
    }
     function loadmoon()
      {
        delete ge;
        google.earth.createInstance('map3d', initCallback, failureCallback, { database: 'http://khmdb.google.com/?db=moon' });
        //http://khmdb.google.com/?db=moon
      }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="init()" style="font-family: arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; border: 0;">
    <div id="map3d" style="width: 500px; height: 380px;"></div>
    <br>
    <a href="" onclick="loadmoon()">LOAD THE MOON</a>
    <div>Installed Plugin Version: <span id="installed-plugin-version" style="font-weight: bold;">Loading...</span></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

This works in that it reloads the instance, BUT it does NOT change the database.

I should say that I am aware of the option of adding a side database, but if I try to load a side database the Terrain is still mapped to the terrain of the first database. For me this is not acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Set the innerHTML of 'map3d' to an empty string before creating  the instance again.

```
function loadmoon(){
    document.getElementById('map3d').innerHTML = '';
    google.earth.createInstance('map3d', initCallback, failureCallback, { database: 'http://khmdb.google.com/?db=moon' });
}
```

Take a look at this example, should be exactly what you need. http://earth-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/examples/alternate-spheres.html